# Heroku app fails to connect to mongodb atlas server (after migration from mlab)

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab, mongodb-atlas

I recently migrated from mlab to mongodb atlas due to its deprecation. I managed to successfully get a connection to the db and tested it with the mongoDB compass but when I add the environment variable to heroku it gives me the following error message:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster-grwbxfbx-shard-00-02.e6jtl.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to cluster-grwbxfbx-shard-00-02.e6jtl.mongodb.net:27017 closed
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726144+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:372:9)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726144+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726145+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726145+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.js:676:12
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726146+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:568:7)]
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726147+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726147+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726148+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726149+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1009:9
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726149+00:00 app[web.1]: at callback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:97:5)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726150+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:124:7
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726150+00:00 app[web.1]: at _callback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:349:5)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726151+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.errorHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:365:5)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726151+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726151+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726152+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:370:12)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726152+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726153+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726153+00:00 app[web.1]: at net.js:676:12
2020-11-11T23:53:44.726153+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:568:7)
2020-11-11T23:53:44.812696+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-11-11T23:53:44.850554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-11T23:53:44.854049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-11T23:53:47.149749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-11-11T23:53:49.907225+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

It seems as if heroku is adding a port to the end of the MONGODB_URI. Does anyone know whats going on?
my config var in heroku is:

```
MONGODB_URI = mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster-grwbxfbx.e6jtl.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

with username and password being replaced by my admin username and password.

Also here is my code for connecting to the db

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import options from '../config'

export const connect = (url = options.dbUrl, opts = {}) => {
  return mongoose.connect(url, { ...opts, useNewUrlParser: true })
}
```

```
export const config = {
  secrets: {
    jwt: 'learneverything'
  },
  dbUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/api-design'
}
```

Let me know if you need me to post anything else

Comment: the port is the default port (the request has to land somewhere). **Troubleshooting**: 1. Did you whitelist the new IP in Atlas? Try using 0.0.0.0/0 first time. 2. Also check if the Cluster is up and running (probably is). 3. Is cluster the name or cluster0?

Comment: I whitelisted the IP and it worked thanks!